# why doesn't the part file have nothing in HIVE ouput

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hive

My issue is i have tried this on my local machine with hadoop and used AWS EC2 to check, there are no return of records in the below query. Now the below script is correct and i know that for a fact?

My quesiton is why we don't see any results in the part file after the job is complete

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS batting;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batting(id STRING, year INT, team STRING,
league STRING, games INT, ab INT, runs INT, hits INT, doubles INT, triples
INT, homeruns INT, rbi INT, sb INT, cs INT, walks INT, strikeouts INT, ibb
INT, hbp INT, sh INT, sf INT, gidp INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://hive-test1/batting';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master(id STRING, byear INT, bmonth INT,
bday INT, bcountry STRING, bstate STRING, bcity STRING, dyear INT, dmonth
INT, dday INT, dcountry STRING, dstate STRING, dcity STRING, fname STRING,
lname STRING, name STRING, weight INT, height INT, bats STRING, throws
STRING, debut STRING, finalgame STRING, retro STRING, bbref STRING) ROW
FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION
's3://hive-test1/master';
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://hive-test1/output' SELECT n.fname,
n.lname, x.year, x.runs FROM master n JOIN (SELECT b.id as id, b.year as
year, b.runs as runs FROM batting b JOIN (SELECT year, max(runs) AS best     FROM
batting GROUP BY year) o WHERE b.runs=o.best AND b.year=o.year) x ON
x.id=n.id ORDER BY x.runs DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Hive to create the two tables, all you're doing is creating a definition of name, field and their types, location and so on.  Create does nothing with data.

Based on your similar question earlier, I think you have some existing HDFS files in CSV format that contain the data you want to query, right?

Before doing that I suggest that you manually insert a record into each table, like`INSERT INTO batting (id, year, team,league) VALUES ('1', 2016, 'Red Sox', 'AL Easr');`. Then, query the table with `SELECT * FROM batting;` to confirm you have on record with some values in it.

Now you have the next problem to solve: how do I import an HDFS file to a Hive table?  You can do this using Hue, if you have it installed.  If not, I suggest you use Google to find an answer to this question.

In general, you have three problems to solve:

1. Create tables in Hive so the Hive megastore knows about their structure.  This is called data definition langurs, or DDL in SQL.
2. Import and Lin your existing CSV data sets sitting as files on HDFS to their corresponding Hive tables
3. Query the tables using SQL likely using SELECT and JOIN, this is called data manipulation language or DML in SQL.

Each is a different step.  Make them work, one by one and you'll take a complex problem and break it down into smaller problems that are easier to understand.